# How does one celebrate Pesach Sheni?

Tags: pesach-sheni

With the current public health circumstances and possibly heading toward limitation of even gatherings with extended family, unfortunately many people may be in  a situation of not holding their usual seder this year. One should still hold a seder with the essential elements, even if by himself. This question is not about or disputing that.

I wonder if people will find a new interest in Pesach Sheni as a date to get together and do something, having missed doing something together on Pesach. It is not a date for an alternative seder, but it exists for those who could not bring the sacrifice on Pesach.  So my question:

**What practices go with Pesach Sheni?**

Comment: Just thinking out loud regarding when klal Yisrael fasted on pesach with regards to Mordechai and Esther. I have no idea if they had Seder or somesorts on pesach shaini.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. All pesach sheni practices that I've heard of are relatively recent innovations. Classically the day was not noted in any way (post Temple). But I also wonder if some one time event has ever happened before.

Comment: I like this question, but it seems like you are asking two things at once. Better to separate them so answers can stay focused. 1) list of all p2 practices, 2) historical major p2 one time events

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess I am, wondering what people do in "normal" years, but also what has been done in crisis years. I'll stick with the former.